# Using Google App Engine coonfusion

Tags: iphone, google-app-engine, google-cloud-storage, google-cloud-sql

I'm Cococa programmer, but right now I encountered situation when I can't go any further without smarter people:)

I always used small databases in my applciations. I programmed PHP backend on my own server and it worked good.

Right now I have to switch for something much bigger and I decided to try with Google App Engine, because it is relatively cheap and has great scalability.

I'm so confused with documentation and I really don't know where to start.

My new app will store data (images, videos) as well as database (mysql) in google cloud.

I concluded that for app like that I should use:

- Google Cloud Storage for images / viedos etc.
- Google Cloud SQL for CRUD operations for users (inserting and fetching personal data)

I would prefer to use JSON api. Then I don't have to write any Java, Python or GO code, right? Only REST requests for Google Cloud SQL...

My question is : Am I thinking correctly? Should I use these two services?

Answer (score 1):

Google App Engine has a feature called "Cloud Endpoints" ([Java](https://developers.google.com/appengine/docs/java/endpoints/) | [Python](https://developers.google.com/appengine/docs/python/endpoints/))
  that automatically generates a JSON API similar to the APIs that Google provides for its own services (and also generates client libraries in JavaScript, Obj-C, and Java to invoke those APIs), saving you the trouble of writing the REST API yourself and manually serializing/deserializing the request and, instead, focusing on just the business logic that performs the storage and retrieval operations. So, what I would suggest is that you write the code that reads/writes data into the datastore (and cloud storage), but then use Cloud Endpoints to automatically generate your JSON API and client libraries, rather than manually writing that code.

Comment: Please tell me one more thing. Do I think correctly that I should use Google Cloud Storage for storing files and Google Cloud SQL for creating user database? As I correctly understand this is purpose of these services

Comment: So what I have to do is 1. Write my backend code in Java or Python (basicly CRUD operations) 2. Generate Cloud Enpoints 3. Write code for client (iOS).

Answer (score 0):

Your plan seems fine so far. Google Cloud Storage is a great choice for storing a large number of images and movies, and Google Cloud SQL is a great choice for handling smaller, more relational data.

If you're using PHP from app engine, there's built-in support for Google Cloud Storage. See https://developers.google.com/appengine/docs/php/googlestorage/

If you're using PHP from your app that lives somewhere else, you could write to the Google Cloud Storage JSON or XML APIs directly, but there's also a PHP library for the Google APIs that might be easier for you to use: https://code.google.com/p/google-api-php-client/